# JList with custom datatype

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to build up a `JList` with a custom datatype with data from a database.

Here is my code but if I am running it, it ends in a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. The Exception trace log is pointing at the `.toString()` methods of two of my entities.

```
DefaultListModel<ErrorCode> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        
for (ErrorCode codes : errorCodes) {
    listModel.addElement(codes);
    } 
    
logUI.getMainPanel().getjList1().setModel(listModel);
```

My goal is to have that list and if you click on one entry a `JTextArea` should be filled with the content of another field of that selected object.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ErrorCode{" + "id=" + id + ", shortName=" + shortName + ", longName=" + longName + ", deviceType=" + deviceType + '}';
}
```

Comment: Your mistake was neglecting to look at the stack trace of the exception.  It will show you exactly which code is recursively calling itself.  Edit your question and paste the first 100 lines of that stack trace (as text, please, not as an image).

Comment: Good point VGR, thanks for that pointing out the right direction. The exception is telling me that the .toString() methods of two of my entities are causing the exception. It is the standard .toString() methods following Hibernate recommendation.

Comment: OK, got it. Indeed the .toString method caused the exception. Then another question popping up. In order not to change the standard .toString() method of the entity do I have to use a custom ListCellRenderer ???

Comment: The toString implementation you have shown does not make any method calls, so it cannot be the source of a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my toString() method and then it worked.